# Spring Boot - Cloud : /actuator/refresh working but not able to get the changed values on the fly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm learning Spring Boot/cloud/Microservices and I'm very new to this.

As the title says, I'm not able to refresh properties on the fly.

I'm using  spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and spring cloud Finchley.M8, I updated the bootstrap.properties as below:

```
spring.application.name=XXXXX
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
```

I'm sending a POST request to `/actuator/refresh` URL to ensure that properties are refreshed.I'm using the `@RefresheScope`, on Configuration class.

The post request on `actuator/refresh` is returning (I'm using postman)

```
[
    "config.client.version",
    "updated property on GIT"
]
```

But, the request to the my service is not picking up these updated properties.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: There was a bug in boot 2.0.0. Please use boot 2.0.1 and Finchley.M9

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem, and if you are using a @Value to initialize like I do, maybe you could add a @RefreshScope in your class.
https://www.devglan.com/spring-cloud/refresh-property-config-runtime this is for reference

Answer (score 0):

I use spring-boot 2.0.1,and my request is /refresh and  it's works ok.you can try again.
Or you can use spring-boot 2.0.0 and try /refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @Value to get properties then consider adding @RefreshScope at class level.